# Wordpress New Post via ajax call

Tags: ajax, wp-insert-post

I have added this field to the Add New Post page

[image: Images]
And i get data  via ajax into console, I want to update post title and content when i click button "Import Data".

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            jQuery('#button__submit').on('click', function() {
                var link__id = $("#link__id").val();
                var data = { action: 'my_action' };
                var linkapi = 'https://www.example.com/?apikey=123456&i=' + link__id;
                $.post(linkapi, data, function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
            });
        });

add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');
function my_action_callback() {
    if (isset($_POST['link_nonce_field']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['link_nonce_field'], 'link_nonce')) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'post_title', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['title'])));
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently, this is just a work request. What have you tried? What issues are you running into? Have resources are you using as a tutorial or what is your research?

Comment: I tried to update post title and content by multi ways, all failed. This is my problem. and my code updated.